# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when clicking on a button in objective C

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, viewcontroller, multiview

I am just learning and trying to put forth some of the knowledge with objective c and cocoa.  I have a little program that has a login screen which then displays a main menu.  On the main menu view, there is a button that should load a view to be able to add some data to the app.  When I click on the button, it doesn't fire the IBAction but throws an error

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS [StartMenuViewController performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6080195e9f90

I know that it is because there is an object that is not instantiated when the message is being sent, but I cannot find out why.  Sorry for the code and the novice level here is the main menu view controller StartMenuViewController.m file:

```
#import "StartMenuViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"


@interface StartMenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation StartMenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}


-(IBAction)showStrainView:(id)sender{
    AppDelegate *delegate = nil;
    delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    MasterViewController *addStrainView = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

    [delegate swapView:self.view toView:addStrainView.view];

}
@end
```

here is the StartMenuViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface StartMenuViewController : NSViewController
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *showStrainViewButton;

@end
```

Here is the AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class loginView, MasterViewController,StartMenuViewController;


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{
    loginView *loginView;
    MasterViewController *masterViewController;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@property (strong) loginView *loginView;
@property (strong) MasterViewController *masterViewController;
@property (strong) StartMenuViewController *starMenuViewController;

-(void)swapView:(NSView *)view1 toView:(NSView *)view2;

@end
```

Here is the AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include "MasterViewController.h"
#import "ScaryBugDoc.h"
#import "Strains.h"
#import "loginView.h"

@interface  AppDelegate()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize loginView;
@synthesize masterViewController;
@synthesize starMenuViewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // 1. Create the master View Controller
    self.loginView = [[loginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginView" bundle:nil];

    // 2. Add the view controller to the Window's content view
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.loginView.view];
    self.loginView.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}



-(void)swapView:(NSView *)view1 toView:(NSView *)view2{

    //[view1 removeFromSuperview];

    [self.window.contentView addSubview:view2];
    view2.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}

@end
```

If you need the loginView.h and loginView.m files I can add them as well.  I would appreciate any and all help.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
MasterViewController *addStrainView = [[MasterViewController        alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

[delegate swapView:self.view toView:addStrainView.view];
```

You don't keep a reference to the `MasterViewController` so it gets deallocated even though its view is kept around. Now anytime the view tries to access methods from the view controller, things fail.

You should make `addStrainView` a child view controller of `self` in the above code so the view controller sticks around as long as its view.

Comment: Thank you for that insight.  Its been driving me crazy.  Being that I am a bit wet behind the ears, where would I make the addStrainView a child view controller.  I am just learning the multi view type app.  Apologies for being so off.

Comment: Also, the same code works in the loginView.m file to show the startMenu, is there a reasons as to why it doesn't work in the StartMenuViewController to show the masterViewController?

Comment: Got it!!! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  Much appreciation!!!